# JavaFX: How to find index of TreeItem in a TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a `TreeView` and a `Button` in my program. Whenever this `Button` is clicked, it adds a new element right after the element selected last in the TreeView.
[image]

For example, if I were to select the "Test Action" element and click the "Add" button, it should add another `TreeItem` right after "Test Action", but before "Test Condition".

I've written code so that I can keep track of the element selected last:

```
@FXML
TreeView<String> view;
TreeItem<String> current = root;
view.selectionModelProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>>>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>>> observable,
                    MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> oldValue,
                    MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> newValue) {
                    current = newValue.getSelectedItem();
            }
});
```

However, through the use of the TreeItem, "current", there is no method I can use to find its index in the TreeView.

*This is so that I can do:*

```
root.getChildren().add(index, new TreeItem<String>(new OpenBank().getAction(), Icons.ACTION.getIcon()));
```

So is there a way to find a child's index in a `TreeView`?

Comment: adding a listener to the _selectionModelProperty_ is useless - it never (or very rarely, not in usual application contexts) changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `TreeItem` has a method [`getParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#getParent%28%29), which returns the parent of the specified `TreeItem`. This parent, which is also a `TreeItem` has a method [`getChildren`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#getChildren%28%29) to get the child `TreeItem`s; the order of `TreeItem`s in the returned `ObservableList` is the actual order that you can see on the screen, therefore you can insert a new element in a specific index with [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) after you retrieved the index of the element in the list with [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

**You can simply handle the current selection in the event listener of your `Button`:**

```
Button b = new Button("Add");
b.setOnAction(event -> {
    // Get the selected item
    TreeItem<String> selectedItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    // If there is no selection or the root is selected do nothing
    if (selectedItem == null || selectedItem == rootNode)
        return;

    // Otherwise get the index of the Node from the children of its parent
    // and append the new item right after it
    int index = selectedItem.getParent().getChildren().indexOf(selectedItem);
    selectedItem.getParent().getChildren().add(index+1, new TreeItem<>("New Item"));
});
```

**If you already tracking the current selection:**

The modification is just to use `current` (that's how you named your variable) rather than getting the selection in the handler:

```
Button b = new Button("Add");
b.setOnAction(event -> {
    // If there is no selection or the root is selected do nothing
    if (current == null || current == rootNode)
        return;

    // Otherwise get the index of the Node from the children of its parent
    // and append the new item right after it
    int index = current.getParent().getChildren().indexOf(current);
    current.getParent().getChildren().add(index+1, new TreeItem<>("New Item"));
});
```

Comment: I think this only works for this specific situation of a tree of depth 1. Do you know of an efficient way of doing it for arbitrary trees?

Comment: It should work on any level. For example if you have a tree with three levels if you select a level3 leaf, it will add a new level3 leaf. If you select a level2 branch, it will add a new level2 branch. What it does not do: does not add a new level3 leaf to a level2 branch, but it is a different functionality.

Comment: note: the _current_ in the question is always the root ;) Tracking would be a bad idea anyway as keeping aliases mostly is.

Answer (score 0):

[TreeItem::getRow](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#getRow(javafx.scene.control.TreeItem))

> Returns the index position of the given TreeItem, assuming that it is
> currently accessible through the tree hierarchy (most notably, that
> all parent tree items are expanded). If a parent tree item is
> collapsed, the result is that this method will return -1 to indicate
> that the given tree item is not accessible in the tree.

Comment: basically true, but doesn't help for the task (adding an item after the currently selected)